# Another "There is already an open DataReader associated......"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, postgresql

Any tips how to close the `DataReader`? I use postgresql and MARS is only for SQL. Or maybe I don't need MARS for this problem I don't know. The error shows in the foreach loop. Thank you for your tips.

```
var months = (from month in connector.PositionInstance where month.FeeNoticeMonth >= DateTime.Now.Month select month);

foreach (PositionInstance p in months)
{
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("" + p.First().Position.Name);
}
```

EDIT:
i have two tables PositionInstance and Position:

```
CREATE TABLE "Position"
(
"PositionId" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT,
"Name" character varying(30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "PK_Position" PRIMARY KEY ("PositionId")
)

CREATE TABLE "PositionInstance"
(
"PositionInstanceId" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT,
"FeeNoticeYear" integer NOT NULL,
"FeeNoticeMonth" integer NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "PK_PositionInstance" PRIMARY KEY ("PositionInstanceId"),
CONSTRAINT "FK_Position_PositionInstance" FOREIGN KEY ("PositionId")
REFERENCES "Position" ("PositionId") MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION 
)
```

Comment: cannot see the whole code but did you try and add a ToList() to your linq statement?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is probably happening in your case due to lazy loading, which is happening inside of the `foreach` loop. It's trying to load each `Position` from the DB on each iteration of the loop.

One way around this is to use eager loading to get all the `Positions` at once in your query. Then if you also use a greedy operation such as `ToList()` at the end of your query, the DB is executed and everything is pulled in one go. In your case try something like

```
var months = 
    (from month in connector.PositionInstance 
     where month.FeeNoticeMonth >= DateTime.Now.Month 
     select month).Include("Position").ToList();
```

or some variation. Using use the `ToList()` after the query will type variable `months`  as a `List` (which is an `IEnumerable`) containing the populated results from the DB; otherwise `months` will be an `IQueryable` with the DB query not yet executed.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this in the connection string:

MultipleActiveResultSets=True

Comment: i use postgresql. I thought MARS is only for SQL